# How to remove/hide GitExtensions toolbar from Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I tried:

- right-click on a toolbar and uncheck GitExtensions
- right-click on a toolbar > Customize and delete GitExtensions
- moved the toolbar from the second row to the first row
- searched GitExtensions settings for a way to disable/hide the toolbar, but didn't find anything

The GitExtensions toolbar shows up again on the second toolbar row after a computer restart.

I use:

- Windows 8
- Visual Studio 2012
- Git 1.7.11
- GitExtensions 2.41

Comment: You've asked the same question on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141780/how-to-remove-hide-gitextensions-toolbar-from-visual-studio

Comment: @VenkatH Is there a problem with that?

Comment: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1493

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (accepted) answer here worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141780/how-to-remove-hide-gitextensions-toolbar-from-visual-studio

> The Git Extension files are stored in your 'My Documents' folder in a
>   "Visual Studio 2012" subfolder. Removing these files will make the
>   toolbar disappear from within MSVC.
>
> More specifically, they're under "Addins". Two .dlls with gitplugins
>   in the name. Kill those and the annoying context menu stuff goes away
>   next time you restart vs.net.

Answer (score 0):

When you tried that, did you happen to have multiple instances of Visual Studio running?

The last Visual Studio instance closed overrides all the settings made through the other instances, so that could be a reason why your settings are not preserved.

Comment: I know that about multiple instances and I only had one instance running.